# MySQL CASE to update multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I would like to update multiple columns in my table using a case statement, but I cannot find how to do this (is this even possible). I came up with the following invalid reference query:

```
UPDATE tablename SET
    CASE name
        WHEN 'name1' THEN col1=5,col2=''
        WHEN 'name2' THEN col1=3,col2='whatever'
        ELSE col1=0,col2=''
    END;
```

Is there any way of achieving the expected result with valid SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358642/case-statement-in-sql-how-to-return-multiple-variables

Comment: Not really, this is an update statement, not a select one.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3432/1553851

Comment: Again, not really. This is an update statement, not an insert one.

Comment: You asked if there was *anyway of achieving the same thing in valid SQL*. The answer is yes, using an insert statement. Note that the linked question is also asking how to combine updates.

Comment: It is not the same thing if it inserts records instead of only updating existing records. The accepted answer to the linked question is an insertion whereas I was explicitly looking for an UPDATE only answer. The linked question indeed also wants an UPDATE answer, but has an INSERT answer accepted. I don't know why this happened, but it would not answer this question.

Comment: Because it doesn't insert records if there are duplicate values for a unique key. I take it there's no unique key on `name`?

Comment: There is not, and I didn't know the IDs in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col1 = CASE WHEN name = 'name1' THEN 5 
                WHEN name = 'name2' THEN 3 
                ELSE 0 
           END
 , col2 = CASE WHEN name = 'name1' THEN '' 
               WHEN name = 'name2' THEN 'whatever' 
               ELSE '' 
          END
;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm going to use ean5533's format since it includes the CASE name, but this one is better formatted so I marked it as the anser.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know that was valid syntax.  Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of any clean way to do what you're asking. An equivalent valid SQL update would be:

```
UPDATE tablename SET
    col1 = CASE name WHEN 'name1' THEN 5 WHEN 'name2' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END,
    col2 = CASE name WHEN 'name1' THEN '' WHEN 'name2' THEN 'whatever' ELSE '' END;
```

Of course this isn't pretty and requires repeating the same cases (e.g. `'name1'`) multiple times, but I just don't think it's possible any other way.

Comment: This does the trick, and the repeating won't be that hard for PHP to handle =) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `name` has a unique index and your values are known to exist in the table, you can use this trick:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name, col1, col2)
VALUES ('name1', 5, '')
     , ('name2', 3, 'whatever')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       col1 = VALUES(col1)
     , col2 = VALUES(col2);
```

If there are any additional `NOT NULL` columns without a default value, you'll have to add dummy values for those. Just leave them out of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and they'll be ignored.