# how to update multiple column with condition in a single sql query

Tags: mysql

I want to update multiple column with multiple condition. 
for.eg.

```
update student set name='john' where id=10 
update student set name='doe' where id=5
```

How  to update this in a single statement?

Comment: Check this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673890/mysql-case-to-update-multiple-columns

Comment: Also, why do you mind making separate statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN`

```
update student 
set name= CASE WHEN id = 5 THEN 'john'
               WHEN id = 10 THEN 'doe'
               ELSE name 
           END
where id in (
    5, 10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update tablename 
set coloumn_name1= CASE WHEN coloumn_name = 5 THEN 'john'
               WHEN coloumn_name = 10 THEN 'doe'
               ELSE name 
           END
where coloumn_name in (
    5, 10
)
```