# How to display multiple rows or one row, depending on the condition, in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am revising a SQL Developer query that pulls transaction data for salespeople from the selected period; the selected period is always a month, e.g. where periodname = 'March 2017'.

However, some of the salespeople are paid monthly, while others are paid quarterly. With the current query, if a quarterly salesperson has a transaction in January, but does not have a transaction in February or March, they would only show up on the January 2017 pull.

I would like to return all transactions QTD for quarterly salespeople, and continue returning transactions MTD for monthly salespeople; i.e. if I run the query for March 2017, a quarterly salesperson would see any transactions from January 2017, February 2017, and March 2017, while a monthly salesperson would only see transaction for March 2017. If I run the query for June 2017, a quarterly salesperson should see any transactions from April 2017 and June 2017, and a monthly salesperson would see transactions from June 2017.

My table has these key elements:

```
    PERIODSEQ  PARENTSEQ  SALESPERSONNAME TRANSACTIONTYPE  PAYFREQ
    109        106        Doe, John       in-store order   Quarterly
    111        110        Doe, John       online order     Quarterly
    112        110        Smith, Jane     online order     Monthly
```

Each monthly period has a period sequence ID; each period sequence has a parent sequence ID that more broadly organizes the periods in a period table. For example, above, the period seq 109 is March 2017, and is part of the parent seq 106, which is called Quarter 1. See below for an example of what the period table looks like:

```
    PERIODSEQ   PERIODNAME     PARENTSEQ
    106         Quarter 1      105
    107         January 2017   106
    108         February 2017  106
    109         March 2017     106
    110         Quarter 2      105
    111         April 2017     110
    112         June 2017      110
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358642/case-statement-in-sql-how-to-return-multiple-variables) was helpful for me, as I had previously been attempting to use a `case` statement to return multiple values, i.e.

```
    case when payfrequency = 'Quarterly' then add_months(sysdate, -3)
```

or

```
    case when transactiontable.parentseq = periodtable.parentseq then add_months(sysdate, -3)
```

but the aforementioned post clearly outlined that a `case` statement does not return multiple values. I have also tried to use `union` statements, and having each of the `where` conditions referencing either Monthly or Quarterly, respectively, but I am still not sure this will pull multiple values:

```
    select * from (
    select r.periodseq, r.parentseq, r.name, r.transactiontype, r.payfreq
    from transactiontable r
    inner join periodtable p
      on p.periodseq = r.periodseq
    where r.payfreq = 'Monthly'
    and r.periodseq = p.periodseq
    and p.periodname = 'April 2017' )
    UNION ALL
    select * from (
    select s.periodseq, s.parentseq, s.name, s.transactiontype, s.payfreq
    from transactiontable s
    inner join periodtable p
      on p.periodseq = s.periodseq
    where r.payfreq = 'Quarterly'
    and s.periodstartdate <= p.startdate
```

Will this logic work? I only have test data for April 2017, and with this query am still seeing all the transactions I would like to see. I just am not sure this is the ideal solution, or if it will actually work when more periods are added to my test data.

Is there a better way to write the query to get the result I'm looking for? Perhaps I could revise the query to utilize parent seq/period seq more effectively?

Comment: Why are you asking if it will work?  looks like you have already worked it out, you just need to run the query.