# select multiple columns on case

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case, case-when

I have the following postgresql select

```
       SELECT 
            col1,
            col2,
            col3,
       CASE
           WHEN var = 1
            col4,
            col5,
            col6
           WHEN var = 2
            col7,
            col8,
            col9
           WHEN var =3
            col10,
            col11,
            col12
        END 
FROM A JOIN B .....
```

so i just want to select different columns on this *CASE WHEN*  condition
but this statement return an error due to case returns only one value, is there any ways to make this work?

Comment: Try executing dynamic sql query.

Comment: A case expression returns _one_ value.

Comment: You can write a separate `CASE WHEN` for each column. But I think it's better, you should ask for your real problem and not a theoretical solution.

Comment: you can find related answer on this thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358642/case-statement-in-sql-how-to-return-multiple-variables

Answer (score 2):

You need multiple `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
       (CASE WHEN var = 1 THEN col4
             WHEN var = 2 THEN col7
             WHEN var = 3 THEN col10
        END),
       (CASE WHEN var = 1 THEN col5
             WHEN var = 2 THEN col8
             WHEN var = 3 THEN col11
        END),
       (CASE WHEN var = 1 THEN col6
             WHEN var = 2 THEN col9
             WHEN var = 3 THEN col12
        END)
FROM A JOIN B .....
```