# Case expression in postgres

Tags: postgresql, case

I have data in below table format.

| id | qid | oid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 10 |
| 2 | 101 | 20 |
| 3 | 103 | 10 |
| 4 | 102 | 20 |
| 5 | 101 | 10 |

**case expression :**

case when (qid=101 and oid=10) and (qid=103 and oid=10) then 1 else end as output

If above case condition match then output should be below.

| id | qid | oid | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 103 | 10 | 1 |
| 5 | 101 | 10 | 1 |

Comment: `qid` can't hold a value of 101 AND 103 simultaneously. You need an `OR`. `case when (qid=101 and oid=10) OR (qid=103 and oid=10)`

Comment: @JSpratt perhaps the `q` in `qid` means quantum .. so that would explain two states simultaneously :-D

Comment: Just to clarify my earlier point, your `CASE` statement in question is equal to this: `CASE WHEN (qid = 101 AND qid = 103) AND oid = 10 THEN 1 END`. Which means for any one record/row you would need `qid` to be 101 AND 103 which isn't possible based on your data. You can either use an `OR` or write it in multiple statements like peter suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the case statement in more than 1 LINe i.e

```
CASE 
    WHEN (qid=101 and oid=10) THEN 1
    WHEN  (qid=103 and oid=10) then 1 
ELSE end as output
```

Comment: And If both condition matched "1"  like above solution THEN final result should be "1". is it possible?

Comment: Can you have a look at this sample [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358642/case-statement-in-sql-how-to-return-multiple-variables)